# Return file in json content format

Tags: php, json

I have a txt file with this structure:

```
17/02/2016 9:50 [info] "hello"
17/02/2016 10:20 [debug] "world"
```

now I'm trying to read it with:

```
$fh = fopen($this->_logPath, "r");
$content = array(); 

while ($line = fgets($fh))
{
    array_push($content, $line);
}
fclose($fh);

return json_encode($content);
```

the file is readed correctly but, in my chrome extension for try Rest API I get in the json tab:

> unexpected string

how I can return each line in json content? For example a result like this:

```
"trace": {
     info: {
         date: {
             "17/02/2016 9:50" {
                -"content": "hello"
            }     
         }
       } 
     debug: {
          date: { 
             "17/02/2016 10:20" {
               -"content": "world"
              }  
          }
       }
    }
```

or if someone have a better organization I'll glad to see.

Comment: What is the context of your code? You are returning the JSON but where are you returning it to?

Comment: _"chrome extension for try Rest API"_ - sorry, but what are you even talking about?

Comment: Also, all you are doing in your code is build a list. To get an object like the one you are showing, you will have to parse the lines.

Comment: @jsfan I return it on a response from the chrome extension, actually I want manage a better organization of the json encoding instead of a simple array print.

Comment: As @low_rents was asking already. What is the Chrome extension you are talking about?

Comment: This: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo help me to get the response from my rest api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would choose a structure like this:

```
{  
   "trace":[  
      {  
         "date":"17/02/2016 9:50",
         "level":"debug",
         "message":"hello"
      },
      { 
         "date":"17/02/2016 9:50",
         "level":"debug",
         "message":"hello"
      }
   ]
}
```

Notice that trace contains an array of logitems.
To parse your file, following should work:

```
$fh = fopen($this->_logPath, "r");
$content = array(); 
$content["trace"] = array();

while ($line = fgets($fh))
{
    $raw = preg_split("/[\[\]]/", $line); //splits string at [ and ], results in an array with three items
    $entry = array();
    $entry["date"] = trim($raw[0]);
    $entry["level"] = trim($raw[1]);
    $entry["message"] = trim($raw[2]);
    $content["trace"][] = $entry;
}
fclose($fh);
return json_encode($content);
```

for experimenting with json you may enjoy https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ which I've always found very useful.

Comment: Good code, just a little correction in the while, `$raw` instead of `raw` and for take the date `$raw[1]` but this depends how I have formatted the file.

Comment: One question: why this line `("/[\[\]]/` is underlined in red in PHPSTORM?

Comment: On my PC it is not. I'm using PhpStorm 10.0.3, mabye you have an old version?

Comment: No I also have the version 10.0.3 :\ when I hold the mouse on it no text appear, just like this: http://i.imgur.com/50a6F2A.png

Comment: strange! Mabye PhpStorm does not recognise the correct version of php? On my machine all looks fine: http://imgur.com/cGdTjZ7